# Как правильно установить Wine?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема: не могу верно установить Wine. Если мне расскажут, что нужно сделать, что делать не нужно, как это сделать буду очень благодарен, за ранее спасибо!

Comment: Архитектура ОС ? Версия дистрибутива ?

Answer (score 2):

Выберите ваш дистрибутив из списка и там всё пошагово расписано (если у вас Минт, выбирайте Убунту): https://www.winehq.org/download

Comment: Это я и сам находил, нужна ПОЛНАЯ установка: настройка префиксов, правильная установка вайнтрикса, плейолинукс  т.д., да это наглый и громосский вопрос, но ответ на него будет полезен всем начинающим линуксоидам

Comment: Честно говоря, мне сейчас лень писать детальные гайды. Может кто-то ещё вам поможет, а я пасс, извините. Я лично не парюсь с префиксами, у меня он 1 активный для всего. PlayOnLinux считаю громоздким излишеством. Зачем мне, например, 150 раз устанавливать копии .Net одной и той же версии для разных программ? Возможно, конечно, что у вас какие-то программы могут конфликтовать, из за чего придётся установить отдельный префикс, но я никогда с таким не сталкивался на практике. А вообще, тут конечно дело вкуса и от ситуации зависит.